# Help with updating record from marketing cloud to sales cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Is there a way to update the sales cloud record from marketing cloud to sales cloud ?

So , I have a multiselect pick list in sales cloud contact object.

I am using Sync DE to get all the data and with the help of query my standard DE will get update.

Then, I created a journey builder (This is basically for engagement split) and i add email wait activity and engagement split.

I also select Update Contact record .

Now ,Lets say i have 3 value in contact object as a multiselect picklist.
 and once my journey will start so it will update my sales cloud data.

Can anyone suggest me the best approach to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a connector setup between your marketing cloud and sales cloud, I'd recommend using the Sales and Service Cloud Activities which is available within the Journey Builder.

Basically, you'd need to choose the right object where you'd want the update to be made, in your case it would be Contact Activity. Drag that activity to the point in the journey where you'd like the action to happen and within contact activity, you can:

- Create a CRM contact record when a Marketing Cloud contact reaches the activity.
- Update a CRM contact record with Marketing Cloud contact data.

This is possibly the best and easiest way to update back to Sales or Service Cloud since it doesn't require any complex script writing and has an interactive user-friendly interface.

**Update:**
If you have a picklist within the Contact object then you'd be able to get the same picklist during the contact activity setup in journey builder.

[image]

*Reference:*

- [**Sales and Service Cloud Activities**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_sales_service_cloud_activities.htm&type=5)

*Screenshot Reference:*

[image]

Comment: Hello , 
Yes i tried to  do this but my question is lets say you have filed salutation in which you added an query Select * from DE_Name where salutation  equal "Value".
According to the example my value will be Mr.
Now when my DE will enter in the journey builder and updating the records so in my multi select pick list i don't want "Mr." value in my multi select picklist. Rest of the value should be there only .Is it possible ?

Comment: It is very confusing that Journeys in Marketing Cloud offer two ways of updating a Contact: Update Contact (under Customer Updates) and Contact (under Sales & Service Cloud). Only the latter will update the Contact in Sales Cloud. The former will update the Contact in a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud, but this will not synchronize back to Sales Cloud. Oh, and for some reason, the latter will let you choose the DE used as Journey entry, but it is not "recommended", whatever that may mean.